# - cknow/laravel-money v2.4.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel

I get the project to make some edits.

When I open the home page it didn't load anything.

When I run `composer install`

i get this
[image]

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Install the `php7.2-intl` extension. What OS are you on? (On Ubuntu: `sudo apt install php-intl`)

Comment: i m ubuntu brother